# Why can't I talk in the Pearl Dive Chat room?

Tags: support, chat, privileges

Is Stack Exchange reputation different than regular? I have more than 20 reputation, but I don't seem to be allowed to talk in chat rooms.

Comment: Hmm. Try it now?

Comment: @AlexanderGruber much better! Thanks!